# Define a non-cartesian mesh in fipy

Tags: python-3.x, fipy

I am trying to simulate the elementary unit of a 2D system that have a P6mm symmetry in fipy and I would like to define a non-cartesian mesh that describes the system described below. Yet,

```
mesh = fipy.Grid2D(nx = 10, ny = 10, dx = 1., dy = 1.)
```

only returns uniform meshes. I thought of changing the FaceVariable, but it seems it only accepts Boolean variables. I could also simulate a cartesian system equivalent to this one, but there would be redondant data. Would someone have a better approach?

[image: System that I want to modelise, with is a mesoporous silica. The different colours indicate different domains, that are regions with different diffusion coefficients.]

[image: Alternative system description]

Alternatively, I could define my system this way. Is there any objection in doing so ?

Comment: Grid2D is a factory function that produces either a UniformGrid2D nor NonUniformGrid2D, depending on the grid spacings. The documentation for [UniformGrid2D](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.meshes.html#module-fipy.meshes.uniformGrid2D) makes clear that it creates rectangular meshes, but the other documentation for [GridND needs to be clear](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/818) that Cartesian meshes are always produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy does not provide a mesh class for what you want. [UniformGrid2D](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.meshes.html#module-fipy.meshes.uniformGrid2D) could be used as the starting point for an equilateral triangular mesh (or a hexahedral mesh, if really required). StackOverflow isn't the right venue for that, though. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/new) if you'd like to pursue that.

[Gmsh](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Mesh-module) will produce structured, triangular meshes, but I'm not sure it can be forced to produce regular, equilateral triangles.

Comment: Thanks. I added an issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/819